# Can't execute "superset db upgrade"

Tags: apache-superset

## superset db upgrade

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.12) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!   RequestsDependencyWarning) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/superset", line 5, in <module>
    from superset.cli import superset   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/superset/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from superset.app import create_app   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/superset/app.py", line 24, in <module>
    from flask_appbuilder import expose, IndexView   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .api import ModelRestApi  # noqa: F401   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .convert import Model2SchemaConverter   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/convert.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask_appbuilder.models.sqla.interface import SQLAInterface   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/models/sqla/interface.py", line 40, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy_utils.types.uuid import UUIDType   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .aggregates import aggregated  # noqa   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/aggregates.py", line 372, in <module>
    from .functions.orm import get_column_key   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/functions/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .database import (  # noqa   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/functions/database.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .orm import quote   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/functions/orm.py", line 14, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.orm.query import _ColumnEntity ImportError: cannot import name '_ColumnEntity'
```

`pip3.6 list |grep  urllib3 urllib3 1.26.12`

I was to install superset on RHEL8 with step.

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++ libffi-devel python3-devel python3-pip python3-wheel

pip3 install apache-superset --ignore-installed PyYAML
```

When i execute  superset db upgrade output error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logs show you are using Python version 3.6.
Superset supports python version 3.7 and higher. Upgrade your python version and retry the installation